# Enable-ReceiveLocation powershell biztalk

Tags: powershell, biztalk

How do I enable a receive Location for BizTalk on a network share? can anyone throw some light on this?

```
Example:Enable-ReceiveLocation -Path '\\t1\apps\Appli1\ReceiveLoc1'
```

I'm getting error currently

> Enable-ReceiveLocation : Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.
>       At line:1 char:1
>       + Enable-ReceiveLocation -Path

Comment: Have you installed the Powershell Provider for BizTalk?  https://psbiztalk.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes. i was able to import bindings and applications fine. do i need to do set-location to certain place to enable receive locations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do this myself. Posting this so it would help others.

TO Enable\Disable a receive location we need to traverse to location

```
Set-Location 'BizTalk:\All Artifacts\Receive Locations'
```

and then issue the ENable/Disable Receive Location command